# WordPress Gravity forms - reCAPTCHA fields keeps failing

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, recaptcha

On a Gravity Form I am implementing on a WordPress site, I keep on getting the error message "CAPTCHA failed. Please try again!" for the reCAPTCHA field.

Any suggestions how I can resolve this?

[reCAPTCHA failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84PFk.png)